# Finding the dominant topic in each sentence in topic modeling

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, topic-modeling

One question that I can't find the answer for in R is that how I can find the dominant topic in NLP model for each sentence?
Imagine I have data frame like this:

```
comment <- c("outstanding renovation all improvements are topoftheline and done with energy efficiency in mind low monthly utilities even the interior",
             "solidly constructed lovingly maintained sf crest built",
             "one year since built new this well designed storey home",
             "beautiful street large bdm in the heart of lynn valley over sqft bathrooms",
             "rare to find legal beautiful upgr in port moody centre with a mountain view all bedroom units were nicely renovated",
             "fantastic opportunity to get value for the money excellent family home in desirable blueridge with legal selfcontained bachelor suite on the main floor great location close to swimming ice skating community",
             "original owner tired but rock solid perfect location half a block to norquay elementary school and short quiet blocks to slocan park and sky train station")

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

data <- data.frame(id, comment)
```

I do preprocess as shown below:

```
text_cleaning_tokens <- data %>% 
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, comment)
text_cleaning_tokens$word <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', text_cleaning_tokens$word)
text_cleaning_tokens$word <- gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', text_cleaning_tokens$word)


text_cleaning_tokens <- text_cleaning_tokens %>% filter(!(nchar(word) == 1))%>% 
  anti_join(stop_words)

stemmed_token <- text_cleaning_tokens %>% mutate(word=wordStem(word))


tokens <- stemmed_token %>% filter(!(word==""))
tokens <- tokens %>% mutate(ind = row_number())
tokens <- tokens %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = ind, value = word)
tokens [is.na(tokens)] <- ""
tokens <- tidyr::unite(tokens, clean_remark,-id,sep =" " )
tokens$clean_remark <- trimws(tokens$clean_remark)
```

The I ran `FitLdaModel` function on this data and finally, found the best topics based on 2 groups:

```
             t_1            t_2
1         beauti          built
2          block           home
3          renov          legal
4       bathroom          locat
5            bdm       bachelor
6      bdm_heart  bachelor_suit
7  beauti_street  block_norquai
8    beauti_upgr       blueridg
9        bedroom blueridg_legal
10  bedroom_unit   built_design
```

now based on the result I have, I want to find the most dominant topic in each sentence in topic modelling. For example, I want to know that for comment 1 ("outstanding renovation all improvements are topoftheline and done with energy efficiency in mind low monthly utilities even the interior"), which topic (topic 1 or topic 2) is the most dominant?

Can anyone help me with this question? do we have any package that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty easy to work with **quanteda** and **topicmodels**. The former is for data management and quantitative analysis of textual data, the latter is for topic modeling inference.

Here I take your `comment` object and transform it to a `corpus` and then to a `dfm`. I then convert it to be understandable by **topicmodels**.

The function `LDA()` gives you all you need to easily extract information. In particular, with `get_topics()` you get the most probable topic for each document. If you instead want to see the document-topic-weights you can do so with `ldamodel@gamma`. You will see that `get_topics()` does exactly what you asked.

Please, see if this works for you.

```r
library(quanteda)
#> Package version: 2.1.2
#> Parallel computing: 2 of 16 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'quanteda'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     View
library(topicmodels)


comment <- c("outstanding renovation all improvements are topoftheline and done with energy efficiency in mind low monthly utilities even the interior",
             "solidly constructed lovingly maintained sf crest built",
             "one year since built new this well designed storey home",
             "beautiful street large bdm in the heart of lynn valley over sqft bathrooms",
             "rare to find legal beautiful upgr in port moody centre with a mountain view all bedroom units were nicely renovated",
             "fantastic opportunity to get value for the money excellent family home in desirable blueridge with legal selfcontained bachelor suite on the main floor great location close to swimming ice skating community",
             "original owner tired but rock solid perfect location half a block to norquay elementary school and short quiet blocks to slocan park and sky train station")

mycorp <- corpus(comment)
docvars(mycorp, "id") <- 1L:7L

mydfm <- dfm(mycorp)

# convert the DFM to a Document Matrix for topicmodels
forTM <- convert(mydfm, to = "topicmodels")

myLDA <- LDA(forTM, k = 2)

dominant_topics <- get_topics(myLDA)
dominant_topics
#> text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text6 text7 
#>     2     2     2     2     1     1     1

dtw <- myLDA@gamma
dtw
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.4870600 0.5129400
#> [2,] 0.4994974 0.5005026
#> [3,] 0.4980144 0.5019856
#> [4,] 0.4938985 0.5061015
#> [5,] 0.5037667 0.4962333
#> [6,] 0.5000727 0.4999273
#> [7,] 0.5176960 0.4823040
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks so much. this is exactly what I want. I just have one question. I am wondering where I should do the cleaning. If you have a look at my code, I am doing bunch of cleanings on my documents, should I do this before making a corpus or after that?

Comment: Also, would you be able to explain where you used `quanteda` package. Your solution seems to be clean and perfect but I just don't know why we have `dfm` or what `docvars(mycorp, "id") <- 1L:7L` and `forTM <- convert(mydfm, to = "topicmodels")` lines doing

Comment: Also, my main data frame had already had `id` as some sort of document number. Instead of assigning 1 to 7, how can I use the same id that I had in my original database, in your approach. I am guessing that you are adding IDs, using `docvars(mycorp, "id") <- 1L:7L` but what if I want to use actual `id` we had? some numbers like forexample " 192,167,189,..."

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other answer that `quanteda` and `topicmodels` are a better choice. Maybe also look into [`seededlda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seededlda/index.html) which is an LDA implementation from one of the `quanteda` authors (with extra features you don't have to use).

However, if you want to stick with your choice of `tidytext` and `textmineR`, this is how you would do it.

First, I simplified your preprocessing a bit, since you did some steps that seemed unnecessary to me:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

text_cleaning_tokens <- data %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, comment) %>% 
  mutate(word = str_remove(word, "[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]")) %>% 
  filter(!(nchar(word) <= 1))%>% 
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word") %>% 
  mutate(word = SnowballC::wordStem(word))
```

Then I run LDA according to the `textmineR` example:

```r
lda <- text_cleaning_tokens %>% 
  cast_sparse(id, word) %>% 
  textmineR::FitLdaModel(k = 2,
                         iterations = 200,
                         burnin = 175,
                         optimize_alpha = TRUE,
                         calc_likelihood = TRUE,
                         calc_r2 = TRUE)
```

Now all implementations of LDA deliver two important results:

- `phi` (φ) which shows for each **word** in the corpus how it scored on each topic. The higher the phi-value, the more prevalent the word in this specific topic.
- `theta` (θ) which shows for each **document** in the corpus how it scored on each topic. The higher the theta-value, the more prevalent the topic is in the document. (`topicmodels` calls it gamma for some reason.)

In other words, all you have to do to find the most dominant topic in a text is:

```r
lda$theta %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(top = which.max(c_across(everything()))) %>% # find highest value per row dplyr style
  bind_cols(data, .) %>% # bind to original data
  as_tibble() # just for nicer printing
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>      id comment                                                t_1     t_2   top
#>   <int> <chr>                                                <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1 1 . outstanding renovation all improvements are t… 0.892   0.108       1
#> 2     2 solidly constructed lovingly maintained sf crest … 0.0161  0.984       2
#> 3     3 one year since built new this well designed store… 0.0238  0.976       2
#> 4     4 beautiful street large bdm in the heart of lynn v… 0.986   0.0139      1
#> 5     5 rare to find legal beautiful upgr in port moody c… 0.992   0.00820     1
#> 6     6 fantastic opportunity to get value for the money … 0.266   0.734       2
#> 7     7 original owner tired but rock solid perfect locat… 0.00549 0.995       2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I also recommend you read Julia Silge's stuff on the matter. For example, [this](https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html) and [this](https://juliasilge.com/blog/evaluating-stm/).

Comment: I appreciate your help, the way you explained this made everything much easier for me. Now I have a better understanding of what these parameters are

Comment: Also, for some reason `bind_cols(data, .) %>% ` this potion of code gives me an error says: Error: Input must be a vector, not a function.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the filter out < 1. It makes the number of rows of the modeled dataset shorter relative to the original data, so their dimensions don't match anymore. Ultimately, the two sets can be joined. I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.